# Adjust doi and page number position in IEEE tran.bst

Tags: bibliographies, doi, bibliographystyle

I want to use doi in references. I am using IEEEtran.bst for refernce styling. To add doi, i replace the file with the one mentioned [online](https://people.kth.se/%7Emaguire/myIEEEtran.bst). But the issue is that it shows doi before page number. I want to move doi at the end.
Example of reference

```
P.  Ajitha,  A.  Sivasangariet  al.,  “Vehicle  model  classification  using  deep
learning,”  in 2021 5th International Conference  on  Trends  in  Electronics and  
Informatics (ICOEI).IEEE, 2021.  doi:10.1109/ICOEI51242.2021.9452842 pp. 1544–1548.
```

Here is bibTex

```
@inproceedings{ajitha2021vehicle,
  title={Vehicle Model Classification Using Deep Learning},
  author={Ajitha, P and Sivasangari, A and others},
  booktitle={2021 5th International Conference on Trends in Electronics and Informatics (ICOEI)},
  pages={1544--1548},
  year={2021},
  organization={IEEE},
  doi={10.1109/ICOEI51242.2021.9452842}
}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please show the code for the bib entry. In particular, we need to know which entry type you 're using for this entry.

Comment: @Mico i have updated the post

Comment: I really wouldn't use a bst file -- here, `myIEEEtran.bst` -- obtained from somewhere on the Internet. Instead, I'd employ the standard `IEEEtran` bib style and hand-edit my bib file. Specifically, I would change `doi={10.1109/ICOEI51242.2021.9452842}` to `note={doi: \url{10.1109/ICOEI51242.2021.9452842}}`. A happy side effect of making this change is that the doi information will get placed at the very end of the bib entry.

Comment: thanks, mico, thats a nice trick btw.

Comment: @Mico Unfortunately, the trick you mentioned is not working for me. \documentclass[lettersize,journal]{IEEEtran} and \bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
\bibliography{ref_file} where with the rest of the fields for ARTICLE I add note={doi: \url{here is doi}}. When I move pointer over it, its not opening file. Could you please suggest what to recheck?

Comment: @user3582228 - Does your document load the `hyperref` package as well? And, what happens if you eliminate the space after `doi:` in `note={doi: \url{here is doi}}`?

Comment: @Micro I have tried everything with space without space but nothing is working. Yes, hyperref is there. The solution works with doi: https://doi.org/10.1016/j.infsof.2021.106593 but do not work with doi = {10.1145/2664243.2664277}

Comment: I guess I got the error: I need to add https://doi.org/...... before second doi. Now, its working.